# Filbeat 7.3.2 serviceaccount with clusterrole issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, filebeat, rbac

My Kubernetes user is not admin in the cluster. So I just cannot create a cluster role binding for filebeat service account. I am using auto discover  in filebeat. Can someone help how can I achieve this without clusterrole.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    setup.dashboards.enabled: false
    setup.template.enabled: true
    setup.template.settings:
      index.number_of_shards: 1
    filebeat.modules:
      - module: system
        syslog:
          enabled: true
          #var.paths: ["/var/log/syslog"]
        auth:
          enabled: true
          #var.paths: ["/var/log/authlog"]
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          templates:
            - condition:
                equals:
                  kubernetes.namespace: microsrv-test
              config:
                - type: docker
                  json.keys_under_root: true
                  json.add_error_key: true
                  json.message_key: log
                  containers:
                    ids:
                      - "${data.kubernetes.container.id}"
    processors:
      - drop_event:
          when.or:
              - and:
                  - regexp:
                      message: '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ '
                  - equals:
                      fileset.name: error
              - and:
                  - not:
                      regexp:
                          message: '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ '
                  - equals:
                      fileset.name: access
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_kubernetes_metadata:
      - add_docker_metadata:
    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.3.2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: KIBANA_HOST
          value: kibana
        - name: KIBANA_PORT
          value: "5601"
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: dockersock
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: dockersock
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}

---
```

Cluster Roles and role bindings

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logging
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
  
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
```

I have tried creating non cluster role and rolebinding as below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs:
      - get
      - watch
      - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: logging
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: filebeat
    namespace: logging
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

but I am getting error.

> Performing a resource sync err kubernetes api: Failure 403 pods is
> forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:xxxxx:filebeat" cannot list
> resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope for *v1.PodList|

Comment: Hello @riteshmaurya. Could you please show the `Role` and `Rolebinding` you tried by editing your question?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor pls check now

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it will not work the way you want it and the error you are getting indicates it perfectly:

```
Performing a resource sync err kubernetes api: Failure 403 pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:xxxxx:filebeat" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope for *v1.PodList|
```

Notice the most important part which is: `at the cluster scope`. You could also check whether an action is allowed by executing the [kubectl auth can-i](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands) command. More about that can be found in the [Authorization Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/).

This brings us to the differences between [Role and ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole):

> An RBAC `Role` or `ClusterRole` contains rules that represent a set of
> permissions. Permissions are purely additive (there are no "deny"
> rules).
>
> A `Role` always sets permissions **within a particular namespace**;
> when you create a `Role`, you have to specify the namespace it belongs
> in.
>
> `ClusterRole`, by contrast, **is a non-namespaced resource**. The
> resources have different names (`Role` and `ClusterRole`) because a
> Kubernetes object always has to be either namespaced or not
> namespaced; it can't be both.
>
> `ClusterRoles` have several uses. You can use a `ClusterRole` to:
>
> - define permissions on namespaced resources and be granted within individual namespace(s)
> - define permissions on namespaced resources and be granted across all namespaces
> - define permissions on cluster-scoped resources
>
> If you want to define a role within a namespace, use a Role; if you
> want to define a role cluster-wide, use a `ClusterRole`.

And between [RoleBinding and ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding):

> A role binding grants the permissions defined in a role to a user or
> set of users. It holds a list of subjects (users, groups, or service
> accounts), and a reference to the role being granted. A `RoleBinding`
> grants permissions within a specific namespace whereas a
> `ClusterRoleBinding` grants that access cluster-wide.
>
> A `RoleBinding` may reference any Role in the same namespace.
> Alternatively, a `RoleBinding` can reference a `ClusterRole` and bind that
> `ClusterRole` to the namespace of the `RoleBinding`. If you want to bind a
> `ClusterRole` to all the namespaces in your cluster, you use a
> `ClusterRoleBinding`.

So it is impossible to get the cluster scope permissions by using `Role` and `RoleBinding`.

You will most likely have to ask your Admin to help you solve this issue.